# Is $y'$ a valid notation for $f'(x)$?

Tags: notation

In this context, let us say that:

$$y=f(x)$$

I've seen both the notation $y'$ and $f'(x)$ being used. Are both correct?

Comment: People are often a bit sloppy about notation, but if we're being very careful then $f$ refers to a function whereas $f(x)$ refers to a number -- the number $f$ returns as output when it receives the number $x$ as input.  If we try to make that distinction, then $y = f(x)$ implies that $y$ is a number rather than a function.  If we intend for $y$ to be a function, we could simply say $y = f$.  However, it then seems unnecessary to introduce $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both mean derivative of

Lagrange’s Notation is to write the derivative of the function $f(x)$ as $f'(x)$

Leibniz’s Notation is to write the derivative of the function $y$ as
${dy\over dx}$ or $y$ as $y'$

Some other uncommon notations are:

Euler's Notation for function $D$ as 
$Df$

Newton's Notation for function $y$ as:
$\dot{y}$

In summary
$${dy\over dx} = f'(x) = y'$$

Comment: Newton's Notation is actually being used at my university, in the mechanics courses (I guess that's related to the fact that they're teaching **Newtonian** mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's fine, but if you want to be absolutely unambiguous (about which variable you're differentiating $y$ with respect to), write $y'(x)$.